# Title fields are displayed as a link

Tags: nodes

For me, all referenced fields or all title fields are displayed as links. This fits in the node as well as in views. However, I don't want this at all, but I would like these fields to be displayed exclusively as text fields.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: You can override the twig template(s) to stop putting out the title as a link, for one. Two in Views if you are outputting fields, you can uncheck the linking options.

Comment: Same goes for rendering ER fields on via the *Label* formatter - just edit the settings and uncheck the link option.

Answer (score 0):

You can override node.html.twig from whatever base theme you are using, and alter it so the title does not display as a link.